How to create a Debian package which will always overwrite user-edited files under /etc on upgrade?
I've created a Debian package with a file that is deeply nested under /etc.  (I'm using a local repo for this custom package.)
This package is to be deployed on embedded systems with no front end.  It is more important to make sure that files match the package than that user modifications are preserved.  There should be no user modifications of the package's files under /etc, but I want to make sure that any accidental user modifications (corruptions) are correct on upgrade.
I noticed that when I had manually modified /etc/.../my_file and upgraded the package to the latest version, /etc/.../my_file still contained my modification and didn't match the file in the package.  I don't remember even being asked whether I wanted to keep the local or package version (as I often am with "real" Debian packages).
I understand why keeping local modifications is right for normal packages, but I need to override it.
How can I make my Debian package's files, under /etc, always overwrite local changes?  Ideally without prompting.

Do not do that. /etc/ is about file which can be modified by users. Do like systemd and other package, put your files either in /usr/lib (if they are not modifiable by programs), or in /var/lib/ if it is a dynamic file. Expectation from user is important, packages should not be so special to break user expectations.

There are no users on these embedded systems.  I want to abuse the Debian packaging system to ship complex config.  This config package will never be available to any normal Debian systems.

but it doesn't matter much if there is no users. Do as if there were users. If you try to make too many "this is special case"... you will get a chaos. If configuration is not mean to be modified by users, put in /usr/lib (if it is static), or in /var/lib and adapt paths in sources accordantly. Adapting paths is one of the main reason to have packages (and distributions). The more you diverge, the more you must document, because next developer (maybe on an other package) now must check many more cases (and you see the chaos and/or non-updatable devices).

sidenote: my understanding is, that upgrading a package containing a file in /etc/ will try to preserve any local change (done by an administrator of the box) - otherwise the files will be upgraded just fine. if the system has no users (as you say), then the files in /etc will always be pristine (not touched by a human), and therefore they will be upgraded anyhow. or put otherwise: if there are no users, there cannot be any user-edited files - and therefore i do not understand your question. (apart from that: i agree with the others that you shouldn't do that)

You cannot and mustn't do that. What you are describing would be a stark violation of Debian policy.
What perhaps you meant to ask was "how can I upgrade a configuration-like file from a previous version of this package to a new version if it hasn't been modified by a local administrator?" The ucf package provides logic for this.
Perhaps see also https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-conffiles.html
